# I am trying to get XSL to render an XML attribute with an & tag as &amp

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML tag which has names in it e.g. H&M. The requirement is that it should output as H &amp M. I am unable to achieve this yet.

Comment: Please read the guidelines on asking questions [here]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can start by posting some of your code and show what you have tried

Comment: Hi Ive tried replacing with &#38;' and &amp;&amp'. Neither worked.

Comment: Hi All  None of the escape characters, &#38; or &amp;amp; worked for me. Here's what worked:

Comment: @Mikko: good advice. If you want to offer the Ask guidelines, you can just type `[ask]` in a comment, and it will auto-expand.

Comment: @springblossom: without any code and a detailed explanation of what you have tried, questions of this brevity are not on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

None of the escape characters, & or &amp; worked for me. Here's what worked:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">


    <xsl:param name="text" />
         <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&amp;')">
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&amp;')"/>
                 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&amp;]]></xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&amp;')"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&amp;apos;')"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&amp;apos;')"/>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&apos;]]></xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&amp;apos;')"/> 
              </xsl:when>

             <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
             </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:template>
```

And then call template:

```
<Nm>
                                  <xsl:variable name="suppNm">
                                   <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                                     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Payee/Name" />
                                   </xsl:call-template>
                                      </xsl:variable>                           

                                      <xsl:value-of select="$suppNm" />  
                                </Nm>
```

If anyone knows a better solution, would be very interested to know. I am a total beginner to XSL.

Comment: Please check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946515/xslt-version-1-replace-single-double-quotes/47990084#47990084 , hope it will helpful for you.