# XSLT Version 1 replace single/double quotes

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert replace single/double quotes with `&quot;` and `&apos;` respectively in xml

I am very new to xsl so very much appreciate if someone can help

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: See below answer, hope it will help. Please note that for your future questions please provide more input data with concrete requirements to avoid "Down Votes" from other user.

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic method of replacing it will be better to create separate template with parameters as input text, what to replace and replace with.

So, in example input text is:

```
Your text "contains" some "strange" characters and parts.
```

In below XSL example, you can see replacing of `&quot;` (") with `&quot;` and `&apos;` ("'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <!--template to replace-->
    <xsl:template name="template-replace">
        <xsl:param name="param.str"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.to.replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.replace.with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($param.str,$param.to.replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($param.str, $param.to.replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.replace.with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="template-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="param.str" select="substring-after($param.str, $param.to.replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="param.to.replace" select="$param.to.replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="param.replace.with" select="$param.replace.with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.str"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="template-replace">
            <!--put your text with quotes-->
            <xsl:with-param name="param.str">Your text "contains" some "strange" characters and parts.</xsl:with-param>
            <!--put quote to replace-->
            <xsl:with-param name="param.to.replace">"</xsl:with-param>
            <!--put quot and apos to replace with-->
            <xsl:with-param name="param.replace.with">"'</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then result of replacing will be as below:

```
Your text "'contains"' some "'strange"' characters and parts.
```

Hope it will help.